# Cycles, Abstract algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm new to abstract algebra. Question is: " What are all the elements of the cycle <(1   2)>? "   Is this in fact a "cycle"?   I understood that a cycle was displayed as, say, <4>, i.e. only one element.  Also then, how does one compute (1   3)<(1   2)>(1   2)^(-1) ?  Any insight would really be appreciated.
Note that the cycle on the first line above comprises TWO elements, i.e. "1" and "2", NOT one element, i.e. "12". The same applies to the cycles on the third line; each set of brackets encloses TWO elements, i.e. "1" and "3", "1" and "2", and lastly, "1" and "2". For some reason, I can't show the interspacing in the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element $(1 2)$ of $S_{n}$ is the permutation that maps 1 to 2 and 2 to 1 and fixes all other numbers and $\langle ( 1 2) \rangle$ denotes the cyclic subgroup generated by $(1 2 )$. To determine all elements of $\langle ( 1 2) \rangle$, you simply perform the group operation (which in this case is function composition) until you get back to the identity element. To compute $(1 3) ( 1 2 ) (1 2)^{-1}$, simply compose these permutations and sometimes this is easier (at least when you are first dealing with the subject) to do when the permutations are written in array notation.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. Really appreciated.

Comment: May I ask: how does one compute (13)<(12)> ?  I know that <(12)> = {e, (12) } but how does one incorporate this in (13)<(12)> ?

Comment: It is the set obtained by composing (13) with all elements of $\langle (12) \rangle$. Also the proper way to write angled brackets in LaTeX is with the command \langle and \rangle.

Comment: If this answered your question, then accept it as an answer by selecting the check mark to the left of the answer.

Comment: Thanks again. I'm new to this site and didn't realise "the protocol". Your response explained the matter fully.